# Best option for a Sencha touch offline application

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2, offline

I am starting a new application in Sencha touch 2, general concept of the will be offline, syncing data at the beginning of the app.

I would like to know the best option for this purpose, I am thinking in two different options:
1- save json files to the device and work with them.
Or
2- save json files to SQLite database using Cordova plugin

What would be the best option?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Offline is more a question of domain model integrity and the server-side infrastructure that support those requirements rather than a client-side tooling one.  Modelling the data in a client-side database is only useful if you plan to re-use it heavily throughout an optimistic offline session - it doesn't inherently solve your "offline" problem.  In any case, it's way too broad of a question for SO - even if you actually gave us any detail about your project.

Comment: Yes, definitely.. I will pull the data when the app is fired, the user works with the app and will have local data and it won't be sync with backend until the next time click in a button (for example).. Do you what I mean in terms of details of the app?

Answer (score 1):

senchatouch 2 has built in support for storing to local storage.

They have good examples that I've followed at the URL:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

Answer (score 1):

You can store JSON data using [Couchbase Lite](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/couchbase-lite/index.html) for the offline feature and then use [Couchbase Sync Gateway](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/sync-gateway/index.html) to get your data syncing to and from a remote server.

If you are working with JSON then mind as well use a JSON Document database as it is in the same format too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use sencha touch with cordova, and use [couchbase mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile) for offline storage and sync to server. However, if you are dealing with very simple data, even localstorage might help.